# Periodic Boundary Conditions for a 3D PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to solving PDE's in Mathematica (so I think I'm making rudimentary mistakes here) and I am attempting to solve a 3-dimensional PDE with a particular initial condition.

The initial function takes the form

```
f[0., x, y] == Exp[-(x^2. + y^2.) + 2*x*y]
```

which looks like

[image]

whilst my PDE is of the form

```
D[f[t, x, y], t] ==-I(D[f[t, x, y], {x, 2}]-D[f[t, x, y], {y, 2}])-(x-y)(D[f[t, x, y],{x, 1}]-D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}])-((x-y)^2)f[t, x, y]
```

and I'm having trouble working out how to solve this PDE with this particular initial function as I'd like to define the periodicity along the x=y line.

Thus far I have successfully solved this for the simpler initial condition of

```
f[0., x, y] == Exp[-(x^2. + y^2.)]
```

which looks like

[image]

and is far easier to solve

```
L := 4
UX1 := D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] /. x -> L
UX2 := D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] /. x -> -L
UY1 := D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}] /. y -> L
UY2 := D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}] /. y -> -L
sol = f /.
        First@
         NDSolve[{D[f[t, x, y],t] == -I (D[f[t, x, y], {x, 2}] - D[f[t, x, y], {y, 2}]) - (x - y)*(D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] - D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}]) - ((x - y)^2)*f[t, x, y], f[0., x, y] == Exp[-(x^2. + y^2.)], UX1 == UX2, UY1 == UY2}, f, {t, 0., L}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

which can then be plotted etc. If I attempt a similar solution with my new initial function, and try to insert some of the desired periodicity, ie

```
L := 4
UX1 := D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] /. x -> L
UX2 := D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] /. x -> -L
UY1 := D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}] /. y -> L
UY2 := D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}] /. y -> -L
sol = f /.
        First@
         NDSolve[{D[f[t, x, y],t] == -I (D[f[t, x, y], {x, 2}] - D[f[t, x, y], {y, 2}]) - (x - y)*(D[f[t, x, y], {x, 1}] - D[f[t, x, y], {y, 1}]) - ((x - y)^2)*f[t, x, y], f[0., x, y] == Exp[-(x^2. + y^2.)+2*x*y], UX1 == UY1, UX2 == UY2}, f, {t, 0., L}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

I receive the error

```
NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition (f^(0,1,0))[t,4,y]==(f^(0,0,1))[t,x,4] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain. >>
```

Which seems to suggest that defining the boundary conditions in the manner that I am trying to solve this with isn't possible. Is there any way to solve this PDE in Mathematica the way I'd like to without rotating the coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by "periodicity along the x=y line"? To me this seems to represent b.c. like `f[t, x, L] == f[t, L, x]`, which isn't the one in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I only want to place a comment, but as a new user I'm not allowed to do.
In the boundary conditions you set x==y!

```
UX1 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, L, x]
UX2 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, -L, x]
UY1 = Derivative[0, 0, 1 ][f][t, x, L ]
UY2 = Derivative[0, 0, 1 ][f][t, x, -L ]
```

If you omit these boundary conditions in a first step your problem can be solved after editing your code a little bit:

```
L = 4 ; 
sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1,0,0][f][t,x,y]==-I(Derivative[0,2,0][f][t,x,y] - 
    Derivative[0, 0, 2][f] [t, x, y] ) - (x - 
    y) (Derivative[0, 1, 0][f] [t, x, y] - 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][f] [t, x, y] ) - ((x - y)^2)*f[t, x, y],
    f[0 , x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2 ) + 2 x y]},
    f, {t, 0  , L}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}
, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}] 


Manipulate[Plot3D[Im[sol[t, x, y]], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L} , PlotRange ->{0,1} , Mesh -> All] , {{t, 1}, 0, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"(*,Animator*)}]
```

Comment: Doing that I get the error message  "DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently"

Comment: Have you got any idea as to what I might be doing wrong? I would've thought this would be simple, I must be missing something silly!

Comment: I have no idea, the problem lies in the boundary conditions. My answer-edit gives you a running version of your problem without the boundary conditions.

Comment: That has certainly worked! Thank you for your help!